# How to compare two timezones in python?

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

Example

```
 import pytz
 b=pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome')
 c=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
```

These two timezones have different names but represent the same thing, however

- b==c returns false
- b.zone is different than c.zone

Is there any way to see that b is in reality equal to c?

The concrete problem is that I have to convert the timezone of a pandas data frame, but only if this zone is different than let's say c. The original timezone might be b and in this case I do not want to convert as it would be a lost of time to convert b into c (since they represent the same time zones at the end....)

Thanks for any help.

*Update*:
changed 'CET' into 'Europe/Rome' to make sure that the timezones are the same in the example, using the feedback from an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's kind of ghetto, but I could compare the offsets of both timezones against a given a timestamp.

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()
b.utcoffset(today) == c.utcoffset(today)
```

Comment: Also check if DST transitions are the same between the two timezones using [pytz._utc_transition_times](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/1acdc7f5ab3f4af063ddcd435f79a48a4a8ce079/src/pytz/tzinfo.py#L168). Filter to recent transition times if you only care that the timezones are the same in the future.

Answer (score 8):

They do *not* represent the same thing.

- [`"CET"`](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/cet.html) is *always* UTC+01:00
- [`"Europe/Berlin"`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin) alternates between CET (UTC+01:00) in the winter, and CEST (UTC+02:00) in the summer.

See also:

- [The timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) - specifically, the section "Time Zone != Offset"
- [The dst tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) - covering daylight saving time.

With regards to the edit, [`Europe/Rome`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014e/europe#L1478-L1484) is a distinct time zone.  It is not the same as [`Europe/Berlin`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014e/europe#L1246-L1251), nor [`Europe/Zurich`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014e/europe#L2709-L2713), nor [`Europe/Amsterdam`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014e/europe#L1831-L1837).  At least not for their entire histories.

If you compare their definitions (using the links in the prior paragraph), you'll see that these each aligned to the "EU" rule for CET/CEST at some point in their past.  Rome and Berlin since 1980, Zurich since 1981, and Amsterdam since 1977.  Before those dates, they differed significantly.  Other time zones have different rules as well.

If you're interested in the history of these zones, I suggest reading through the [europe file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/europe) in the TZ data.  The comments alone are quite interesting.

On the other hand, if you are only working with modern dates, where all zones are following the same rules and offsets, then you could consider these substitutable - at least as long as they don't change in the future.

Also, there *are* some time zones that are just aliases and are completely interchangeable.  In the TZ data, they're called "links".  For example, you can see [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014e/europe#L1486-L1487) that `Europe/Vatican` and `Europe/San_Marino` are both linked to `Europe/Rome`, and are therefore equivalent.

Comment: ok, then consider my example with time zone "Europe/Rome" instead of "CET". I think we can conclude that now they are the same but there is still not an intuitive way to find this out

Comment: @Mannaggia: Why do you think Europe/Rome and Europe/Berlin timezones are the same? Even if the utc offsets are the same today, they might be different in the past or in the future.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: as long as they do not differ they should be the same. Also, I expect the two classes implementing these type to have exactly the same implementation and state variables.Therefore I do not see any reason why they should differ.

Comment: @Mannaggia: all timezones with DST transitions are implemented using the same class. It does mean that any instances should be the same e.g., all integer in Python 3 are instances of `int` class. It doesn't mean that all integers should be the same `1 != 2` (though it is easy using version-specific `ctypes` magic to make them equal (with detrimental effect on your program)).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the point is that 'Europe/Rome' is an alias of 'Europe/Berlin' or 'Europe/Zurich' or 'Europe/Amsterdam', etc. So we got plenty of time zones which are an alias of the same underlying concept. Is this not an unnecessary complexity?  I think this is not the same as comparing two different integers which are different instances of the same type. Here the type is timezone and the instances are Europe/Rome and Europe/Berlin... it is like saying that 1 != (2-1)

Comment: @Matt Johnson: thanks for the deep explanation, at the end I needed a fast solution to my concrete problem which was provided by another answer, nevertheless I am grateful for your input

Comment: @Mannaggia: I don't think `'Europe/Rome'` timezone is an alias for `'Europe/Berlin'` even if it happens that they use the same rules **today**. Do you have any reference that says that they are aliases and not separate completely independent timezones?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I do not have any reference but as pointed out by MattJohnson they apparently used to differ before the '80s, fact is that as of today they are the same and most likely they will be the same for many years to come...

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for not wanting to convert is because of inefficiency, I would question whether this is really necessary. There is a good blog post by Wes McKinney on vectorized datetime conversion http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=506. As an example, for a series with 1e6 rows

```
In [1]: from pandas import *
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: rng = date_range('3/6/2012', periods=1000000, freq='s', tz='US/Eastern')
In [4]: ts = Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)),rng)
In [5]: %timeit ts.tz_convert('utc')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.17 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@chrisaycock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266185/1290627), here's a Python function that checks if the utc offset and dst transitions are the same between two timezones:

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

def is_same_timezone(a: Union[pytz.timezone, str, bytes], b: Union[pytz.timezone, str, bytes], relative_to: datetime = None) -> bool:
    """
    Return True if the timezones result in the same utc offset near the relative_to datetime, otherwise False.

    Makes sure UTC offset is the same, at time of `relative_to`.
    Makes sure DST transitions are the same, for the year of `relative_to`.
    Defaults to checking relative to the current year.
    """

    if a is None or b is None:
        return False
    if isinstance(a, bytes):
        a = a.decode()
    if isinstance(b, bytes):
        b = b.decode()
    if isinstance(a, str):
        a = pytz.timezone(a)
    if isinstance(b, str):
        b = pytz.timezone(b)

    relative_to = relative_to or datetime.utcnow()
    if a.utcoffset(relative_to) != b.utcoffset(relative_to):
        return False

    year = relative_to.year
    dsta = list(filter(lambda dt: dt.year == year, a._utc_transition_times))
    dstb = list(filter(lambda dt: dt.year == year, b._utc_transition_times))

    return dsta == dstb
```

I use this for display-only, to show an indicator to my app's users when viewing dashboards in different timezones. If the timezones for the dashboard range match, I don't want to show the indicator. However, I still store the original Olson timezones because it represents a user's preference. Also timezones change, so relative to a different `datetime` the timezones might not align.