# Comparison between pytz and pandas timezones fails

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, pytz

I want to compare the timezone of a pd.DatetimeIndex with a pytz.timezone to see if the DatetimeIndex has the expected timezone. But the comparison fails, possibly because using the tzinfo argument does not work as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36157369/7291091).

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import unittest

tzstr = 'Europe/Vienna'
manual_tz = pytz.timezone(tzstr)

timestamp = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-02 07:00:00+01:00').tz_convert(tzstr)

tc = unittest.TestCase()
tc.assertEqual(timestamp.tz, manual_tz)
```

```py
AssertionError: <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Vienna' CET+1:00:00 STD> != <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Vienna' LMT+1:05:00 STD>
```

How can I check that the timezone of `timestamp` is as expected? It should be the same as `pytz.timezone` in my opinion, but the behavior of pytz and/or pandas makes them somehow different.

*Alternative question formulation if it is not possible to make a comparison like this:* What do I have to look out for, to not come across this problem any more? It did happen to me more than once already. I found a [question similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266185/7291091), but having to use multiple dates to compare if the offset is always the same does not seem like the best way to.

Comment: I am finally using `.utcoffset()` on concrete dates. And in general try to avoid non-UTC tz in my code, only add tz when going to UI / plots.

Answer (score 1):

I think your matter is linked to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474330/11832127)

> The default zone name and offset delivered when pytz creates a timezone object are the earliest ones available for that zone, and sometimes they can seem kind of strange.

This is what I have when I run your code:

```
AssertionError: <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Vienna' CET+1:00:00 STD> != <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Vienna' LMT+1:05:00 STD>
```

What you can do is this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import unittest
import datetime

tzstr = 'Europe/Vienna'
manual_tz = pytz.timezone(tzstr)
pytz_localize = manual_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0))


timestamp = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-02 07:00:00+01:00').tz_convert(tzstr)

tc = unittest.TestCase()
tc.assertEqual(timestamp.tz, pytz_localize.tzinfo)
```

But IHMO, it's weird to have to create two dates for comparing the timezone information.

What do you mean by compare the timezone? What do you want to check?

**Edit**
About testing timezone and conversions. What I would do is find test cases you want to check. Something I would check is that I correctly handle the DST change, for this I would do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# DST in Austria in 2021.
all_dates = ['2021-03-28 01:59:00+0100', '2021-03-28 03:01:00+0200']
utc_dates = pd.to_datetime(['2021-03-28 00:59:00+00:00', '2021-03-28 01:01:00+00:00']).tz_localize('UTC')

timezoned_timestamps = pd.to_datetime(all_dates, utc=True).tz_convert("Europe/Vienna")

# then we check if it's equal after UTC conversion
pd.testing.assert_index_equal(utc_dates, timezoned_timestamps.tz_convert('UTC'))
```

The parameter `utc=True` in the first `to_datetime` call is mandatory:

> However, timezone-aware inputs with mixed time offsets (for example issued from a timezone with daylight savings, such as Europe/Paris) are not successfully converted to a DatetimeIndex. Instead a simple Index containing datetime.datetime objects is returned

From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#to-datetime-tz-examples).

Comment: I am getting dates from a database, which are sent only with an offset. I process the timestamps and convert to a timezone defined by the user, so that time shifts (DST) are handled correctly. As I had problems with the timezone conversion multiple times already, I want to unittest, if the processed timestamp has the expected / user defined timezone in all cases.

Comment: I hope it's okay to copy the output to the question for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the need. I will edit my answer with some precision about testing this point.

Comment: *it's weird to have to create two dates for comparing the timezone information* - I think it's perfectly reasonable you have to set a date here: time zone rules change over time, so UTC offsets depend on the date.

Comment: regarding your edit / example: I don't think it makes sense to set a time zone here in the first place. If the input just has UTC offsets, just parse everything to datetime with `utc=True` and check if the date/times are equal.